# '78 Volkswagen vanagon , battery issue

Tags: vw, charging

Howdy folks I have a 78 Volkswagen vanagon, I'm having battery issues due to the fact my disrespectful son-in-law ripped out my battery when he did this there is a positive cable and a negative cable, the positive cable has a small wire attached to it that has a yellow crimp on the end of it, this is not attached anymore and I cannot find out where it goes to, now my dash light is on , for the charging system, is that cable usually attached to the alternator, I was reading another post and that's what they were talking about so I just thought I would ask this question thank you very much I appreciate you guys any help will be big help, one more thing I had a mechanic that does not work on Volkswagens come over cuz I was desperate and he told me that my alternator was bad and did not know where that cable attaches to so I asked him not to do any work for me cuz he wanted to cut some wires and I know that's a bad idea,

Comment: Can you add a photo of the battery area?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Wiring diagrams for the old VW T2 & T25 are widely available on the web.  A quick search will find one for you.  You can then see where *all* the wires should go.

Answer (score 0):

There are typically two wires attached to the battery at the positive post. One wire (the thick one) goes to the starter. The other wire (a thin one), goes to alternator and is considered a field wire, which provides the current needed to excite the alternator at the proper voltage so it can charge the battery. The wire you are talking about sure sounds like the one which goes to the alternator. It does indeed need to be attached to the alternator or the system won't charge correctly and is most like the cause of your dash light.

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is what the back side of your alternator looks like. The large nut on the left side of the image is the positive post your thinner battery wire should be connected to.

You didn't really mention what shape the alternator end of the wire was in. I'm assuming it was just yanked out. If there is bare wire on that end, you'll need to affix a new connector which can then be located onto the positive (+) post I've shown you in the image above. More than likely, the remains of the old one will still be attached. If it is, it probably will not be salvageable and will have to be removed.